# freemmarker enable JSPSupportServlet

Tags: kendo-ui, jsp-tags, freemarker

My question is very simple. I want to use another taglib with freemarker.
I read in the freemarker doc that  it's possible.
I want to use the kendoui taglib

```
<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
```

the api doc says we must do that by adding a line like

`<#assign html=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld"]>`.

But when  i  do that, i have the error

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> JspTaglibs
```

cordially.

---

thankyou for your answerd. it works thine when i use freemarkerServlet.
But i want to use a single servlet that will allow me to configure freemarker (in init method) and parse the html response  to response writer.

```
req.setCharacterEncoding(cfg.getOutputEncoding());
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=" + cfg.getOutputEncoding());
resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
resp.setHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 00:00:00 GMT");
Writer out = resp.getWriter();
template.process(page.getRoot(), out);
```

in fact, i want to extend freemarkerServlet class as mentionned here : `http://schakrap.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/using-freemarkerservlet-in-google-guice-to-inject-configuration/` .

But i still have the same error.

for the matter what does mean the config parameter TemplatePath ?

Answer (score 0):

The `JspTaglibs` variable, and the whole environment that's needed for custom JSP tags to feel home, is set up by the `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet`. So currently the only way to use taglibs is with `FreemarkerServlet`, which was made so that you can use FTL files instead of JSP files in legacy JSP Model-2 frameworks.

Comment: thank you ddekany for your answerd.
But i don't understand what to do exactly. Do you mean i can't use  <#assign html=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld"]> ?

What i have to do  exactly for using jsptaglib with freemarker?

Comment: You had to use FreeMarker via `FreemarkerServlet`, that is, in a JSP Model-2 fashion. See http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#pgui_misc_servlet_model2.

Comment: in fact, i want to extend freemarkerServlet class as mentionned here : http://schakrap.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/using-freemarkerservlet-in-google-guice-to-inject-configuration/ .


But i still have the same error.



please For the matter what does mean the config parameter TemplatePath ?

Comment: TemplatPath is described here: http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/servlet/FreemarkerServlet.html

Comment: As far as you are invoking the template via `FreemarkerSerlvet` or via a sub-class of it, the `JspTaglibs` variable should aways exist. It's not conditional or something. Aren't you replacing the whole data-model (aka. template context) somehow? `JspTaglibs` is in the data-model.

Comment: I make the following statement:
Template t = cfg.getTemplate ("theme /" + page.getTemplate ());
t.process (page.getRoot (), out);
(Where page.getRoot () is a map)

is this statment replace whole data model?

Do you mean i must past
Should I retrieve the variable JspTaglibs and go to the map before invoking the method t.process?
Something (page.getRoot (). Put ("JspTaglibs" JspTaglibsObject))

if yes how can I retrieve the object JspTaglibs?

Comment: Yes, that replaces the whole data-model, as the data-model is whatever you pass to `Template.process`. For other details you should just check the source code... FreeMarker has quite different mental model than JSP/Servlet. The `FreemarkerServlet` tries to bridge these two worlds, to ease migration, and lot of this bridging happens through the special data-model it creates. It also manages some servlet context attributes AFAIR. So it's probably not as easy as throwing "JspTaglibs" in... JSP taglibs expect a JSP-environment, that will have to be faked somehow.

Comment: What's `page.getRoot()` anyway? In the JSP approach (that `FreemarkerServet` *has* to emulate) the data-model is basically the set of request-, session- and application-scoped attributes. FreeMarker is flexible enough to use those as the data-model, but JSP taglibs won't bend to reach the "native" FreeMarker data-model. So you will have problems if the custom JSP tags want to access data-model variables by name, which are not request/session/app attributes. Hence you can't just use a POJO/`Map` data-model... JSP has its assumptions.

Comment: hi 
page.getRoot()  return a  Map<String, Object>  object. 

Sorry my english is very poor. I'm a little confused about your last message.
Is that I can not use pojo and session attributes (request, application)?
I send you the source code of my servlet in an answer to this thread. please please see if you can give me comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package presentation;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import freemarker.core.Macro;
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;

public class ControllerServlet extends freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet
{
    //
    private Configuration   cfg;
    private Handler handler;

    public ControllerServlet()
    {
        super();
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        String userAgentString = "";

        StringBuffer url = req.getRequestURL();

        String sUrl = url.toString();

        // on instancie les classes/structures pour Freemarker
        FreemarkerParameterMap page = new FreemarkerParameterMap();

        handler = new Handler();

        try
        {
            userAgentString = req.getHeader("User-Agent");

            System.out.println("User-Agent : " + userAgentString);

            handler.handle(req, resp, page);

            if (page.getDataType() == FreemarkerParameterMap.AJAX_JSON)
            {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL).setPrettyPrinting().create();
                Map<String, Object> map = page.getRoot();
                resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(map));
                resp.getWriter().flush();
            }
            else if (page.getDataType() == FreemarkerParameterMap.HTML_REDIRECT && page.getRedirect() != null)
            {
                resp.sendRedirect(page.getRedirect());
            }
            else if (page.getDataType() == FreemarkerParameterMap.HTML_FORWARD && page.getForward() != null)
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher(page.getForward());
                rd.forward(req, resp);
            } 

            else
            {
                if (page.getTemplate() != null)
                {
                    Template t = cfg.getTemplate("theme/" + page.getTemplate());

                    if (page.getDataType() == FreemarkerParameterMap.AJAX_HTML)
                    {
                        Map mapMacro = t.getMacros();
                        Macro macro = (Macro) mapMacro.get(page.getMacro());
                        t = new Template("name", new StringReader(macro.getSource()+"<@"+page.getMacro()+"/>"), cfg);
                    }
                    else if (page.getDataType() == FreemarkerParameterMap.HTML)
                    {
                    }

                    req.setCharacterEncoding(cfg.getOutputEncoding());
                    resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=" + cfg.getOutputEncoding());
                    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                    resp.setHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 00:00:00 GMT");
                    Writer out = resp.getWriter();

                    t.process(page.getRoot(), out);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ServletException("aucune action  specifiée");
                }
            } 

        }

        /*catch (EcoliaException e)
        {
        } */
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * The doPost method of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to post.
     * 
     * @param request the request send by the client to the server
     * @param response the response send by the server to the client
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
     * @throws IOException if an error occurred
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        doGet(req, resp);
    }


    /**
     * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
     */
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        // Initialize the FreeMarker configuration;
        // - Create a configuration instance
        cfg = new Configuration();

        // - Templates are stored in the WEB-INF/templates directory of the Web app.
        cfg.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(getServletContext(), "");

        // - Set update dealy to 0 for now, to ease debugging and testing.
        //   Higher value should be used in production environment.
        cfg.setTemplateUpdateDelay(0);

        // - Set an error handler that prints errors so they are readable with
        //   a HTML browser.

        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER);

        // - Use beans wrapper (recommmended for most applications) 
        cfg.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER);

        // - Set the default charset of the template files
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        // - Set the charset of the output. This is actually just a hint, that
        //   templates may require for URL encoding and for generating META element
        //   that uses http-equiv="Content-type".
        cfg.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");

        // - Set the default locale
        cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);

        System.out.println("init controleur");
    }

}
```

and in the web.xml i have this :

```
<servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>presentation.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```